# Kibana dashboard embedded in iframe redirecting to login everytime, due to same site cookie setting in latest chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

[image: Browser console log for kibana iframe]

When I try to login to kibana(7.6 Version) iframe embedded dashboard it is redirecting to the same login page every time. As per my research on google, I found this is due to chrome browser latest update which enabled SameSite by default cookies default( [Chrome Browser Settings Link](http://chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies) ),
I can able to access the dashboard normally when I disable this setting.
But I am expecting a proper production kind of solution.

Comment: I've commented on this issue: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/60522

Answer (score 2):

You can add the parameter `xpack.security.sameSiteCookies: None` in kibana.yml with ELK stack version above 7.8.0, to allow third-party cookies in iFrame. It can be used in the elastic.co cloud provider.
If you use a reverse proxy, you can add a header for SameSite.

References: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cookies-issue-while-embedding-kibana-dashboard-with-iframe/256777/8